# Why does redux-mock-store don't show an action dispatched in catch promises?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, nock, redux-mock-store

*I'm very bad when it comes to thinking of a title question, sorry for that.*

### My Problem:

I'm unit testing my async redux actions like it's suggested [in the docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html). I mock the API calls with `nock` and check for the dispatched actions with `redux-mock-store`. It works great so far, but I have one test that fails even though it clearly does work. The dispatched action neither does show up in the array returned by `store.getActions()` nor is the state changed in `store.getState()`. I'm sure that it does happen because I can see it when I test manually and observe it with Redux Dev Tools.

The only thing that is different in this action dispatch is that it is called in a promise in a catch of another promise. (I know that sounds confusing, just look at the code!)

### What my code looks like:

**The action:**

```
export const login = (email, password) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestSession());
        return httpPost(sessionUrl, {
            session: {
                email,
                password
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            dispatch(setUser(data.user));
            dispatch(push('/admin'));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            error.response.json()
            .then(data => {
                dispatch(setError(data.error))
            })
        });
    };
}
```

This `httpPost` method is just a wrapper around `fetch` that throws if the status code is not in the 200-299 range and already parses the json to an object if it doesn't fail. I can add it here if it seems relevant, but I don't want to make this longer then it already is.

The action that doesn't show up is `dispatch(setError(data.error))`.

**The test:**

```
it('should create a SET_SESSION_ERROR action', () => {
    nock(/example\.com/)
    .post(sessionPath, {
        session: {
            email: fakeUser.email,
            password: ''
        }
    })
    .reply(422, {
        error: "Invalid email or password"
    })

    const store = mockStore({
        session: {
            isFetching: false,
            user: null,
            error: null
        }
    });

    return store.dispatch(actions.login(
        fakeUser.email,
        ""))
        .then(() => {
            expect(store.getActions()).toInclude({
                type: 'SET_SESSION_ERROR',
                error: 'Invalid email or password'
            })
        })
});
```

Thanks for even reading.

#### Edit:

The `setError`action:

```
const setError = (error) => ({
  type: 'SET_SESSION_ERROR',
  error,
});
```

The `httpPost`method:

```
export const httpPost = (url, data) => (
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: createHeaders(),
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(response => response.json())
);

const checkStatus = (response) => {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }

  const error = new Error(response.statusText);
  error.response = response;
  throw error;
};
```

Comment: It would be great to have a `redux-mock-store` tag.

Comment: It should be on it's way :)

Comment: Please, add a code of setError

Comment: @fahrradflucht if the answer is correct, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of you are using nested async function in catch method - you need to return the promise:

```
.catch(error => {
  return error.response.json()
  .then(data => {
    dispatch(setError(data.error))
  })
});
```

Otherwise, dispatch will be called after your assertion.

See primitive examples:
https://jsfiddle.net/d5fynntw/ - Without returning
https://jsfiddle.net/9b1z73xs/ - With returning